# The expiration date of the patent US 20100203636

Tags: expiration, date, invalidate

In reference to the patent: [US20100203636](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100203636)

Answer (score 0):

Patent application is abandoned due to "Failure to Respond to an Office Action". It is expired during the examination process.

You can use the USPTO's public PAIR database(https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) for legal status. If the patent is active then the patent term is 20 years from its own filing [35 U.S. Code § 154 (a)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/154)

Comment: Could you add the way how you found this information so that the answer can help future visitors with the same question for another patent?

Comment: In addition, the cited document is an application, not a patent.